# Consequences of NOT properly implementing IDisposable

Tags: c#, .net, idisposable

I am comfortable with how to implement IDisposable..

However I'm not clear as to the exact consequences of not implementing this properly. Is it a case that unmanaged resources will never be cleared thus causing memory leaks or will the memory eventually get recycled anyway, just not in a timely manner?

Comment: The MSDN - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737(v=VS.100).aspx just says you must implement it correctly, but not *why*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends.

If the object in question fails to implement IDisposable, but does still implement a finalizer correctly, the resources will eventually get cleaned up.

However, if it doesn't properly implement a finalizer, AND it's wrapping an unmanaged resource, that resource will be leaked.  This is more often a resource leak (ie: leaking a HANDLE stored as IntPtr) more than a traditional "memory leak" (though, of course, the object being pointed to does still use memory).

> will the memory eventually get recycled anyway?

One point here... **IDisposable has nothing to do with memory** - it's about resources.  These resources often use memory of their own, but implementing IDisposable does not cause your garbage collector to reclaim memory more quickly.

Comment: Indeed, how long is a piece of string?

Comment: +1 - i had answered on the basis of memory and garbage collection. but you rightly point out here that it's resources (which do have memory associated) that's the issue here. my nonesense withdrawn :)

Comment: in my answer, I know that IDisposable doesn't reclaim memory, but finalization is run by the GC, and it's finalization code that is likely to free the unmanaged resources if Dispose hasn't been called yet.

Answer (score 4):

It depends entirely on what te implementation is, of course.

An incorrect dispose on a SqlTransaction could lead to excessive long blocking, for example - impacting multiple machines and users. An incorrect dispose on a SqlConnection could cause connection saturation and inability to connect. These are not just memory (etc) issues.

IIRC a missing graphic (pen/brush/whatever) dispose was responsible for a VS crash bug - GC didn't happen because there was no memory pressure, so instead it simply saturated the GDI handles and broke.

An incorrect file/stream dispose could cause exceptions due to a file bring unavailable for reading/writing - potentially losing data.

With unmanaged resources not properly handled, anything is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of thinking in terms of some vaguely-defined "resources", think of IDisposable as meaning "This object manipulates something outside itself (and possibly even outside the computer!) in a way that needs to be cleaned up, while the information necessary for such cleanup still exists."  A finalizer which fires essentially says "Nobody else is using this stuff anymore, and I'm the only one who knows about it; I'd better clean it up because nobody else is going to."

It is dangerous to assume that finalizers will magically take care of things; while many objects can be safely abandoned, many others cannot.  In some cases, it will be easy for an object to detect that it has been abandoned and clean up appropriately.  In some other cases, it may be so difficult as to be impractical.  Consider an object which is supposed to count how many times the word "quack" appears in a long-lived data stream.  If the creator of the object has forgotten about it, and nobody is every going to query the count, the object may as well go away.  Unfortunately, since the data stream holds a reference to the counting object (so as to let it know when data comes in), the counter object won't go away.  If code creates a counter, then forgets about it, then creates another one, forgets about it, etc. this could become an unbounded memory leak.

Answer (score 1):

A class that holds unmanaged resources should ensure that they are cleaned up during finalization. However, this only happens when the garbage collector gets around to it.

Not calling Dispose means waiting for the garbage collector to need memory before the resources are released.

Comment: A class that only holds *managed* resources doesn't need to do anything during finalisation, and almost certainly shouldn't have a finaliser at all.

Answer (score 0):

The latter of the two. Just not in a timely manner.

The importance of this depends on the resources you are allocating. This is why you are more likely to see IDisposable interfaces on objects that open files and reference other, more crticital, resources.

Comment: This is misleading. You're saying that the resource will eventually be reclaimed, but that's only the case if the `IDisposable` type in question implements a "fallback" finaliser (and that's an implementation detail). It's good practice to assume that failing to dispose an `IDisposable` will result in a permanent resource leak; if the implementation happens to implement a finaliser that eventually tidies things up then that's a bonus, not a guarantee.

Comment: @LukeH: I disagree.  An IDisposable that does not implement a finalizer is a bug... It's implemented incorrectly.  I do agree that you should try to always Dispose your IDisposable objects, but not doing so should never result in a *permanent* resource leak.

Comment: @LukeH: There are some (rare) objects where the suggested course of action is to NOT dispose of them - for example, `Task`/`Task<T>` in the TPL are typically not disposed of by you - the internal wait handle, when used, gets cleaned by the finalizer...

Comment: @Reed: I agree that not implementing a fallback finaliser would a bug in the `IDisposable` type itself, but why compound that bug by adding your own bug by not disposing the object? I meant that, in general, you should code *as if* not disposing an `IDisposable` will result in a permanent leak, not that it will actually happen.

Comment: @LukeH: Well, that's kind of like writing code to check that ToString() returns a string and not null... How often do you check for null after calling ToString() on an object?  Or do you just assume that the object implements itself correctly?

Comment: @Reed: Huh? IDisposable is an interface that makes it easier to force an object to free up resources. Resource would include files, system objects, etc. and, yes, memory.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: IDisposable only is about unmanaged resources - which can have associated memory.  My point was that it does NOT have anything to do with reclaiming memory allocated by the CLR.  This is a major misconception.  It's about freeing resources (which indirectly can free that resource's memory)... not about memory management.

Comment: @LukeH: Yes, I'm assuming the classes I'm using know how to clean up after themselves. Also, if the resource is memory, then it will eventually be freed up whether the object cleans up after itself or not.

Comment: @Reed: I see your point but I'm not sure where you're going with it. All I'm suggesting is that, in general, you should dispose any `IDisposable` rather than being blasé and assuming that there's a finaliser that'll cover your back. In the same way, in the general case, you don't need to check whether `ToString` returns null.

Comment: @LukeH: I guess my point is the reason for calling `Dispose()`, in my mind, is not to be a safety check on your implementation, but rather to explicitly specify *when* the cleanup occurs.  Same result in the end (you call Dispose()), but much different motivation behind it.

Comment: @Reed: True. I guess my perspective comes from the fact that finalisation is indeterminate, and an indeterminate "eventually" is no different from "never" in many scenarios. For example, the app I work with would be on it's knees long before the GC started firing any fallback finalisers if I failed to dispose of my database connections.

Comment: Reed on IDisposable without finalizer - this is actually good practice for objects that do not hold unmanaged resources. I.e. some sort of Stream in memory (i.e. System.MemoryStream) should not have finalizer due to extra cost of finalizers for GC. More infor - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163392.aspx

Comment: @Alexei: Yes, but it, technically, doesn't need to implement IDisposable either - since Dispose() does nothing.  The only reason it implements IDisposable is that it's base class (Stream) does...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, unmanaged resources will never be released. (This assumes that the `IDisposable` types in question don't implement a "fallback" finaliser. If they do then the finaliser should sort things out... eventually.)

However, it's not just unmanaged memory allocations that you need to worry about; it's any unmanaged resources. For example, if you don't properly dispose of your database connections then you might find that the connection pool quickly gets exhausted.

Answer (score 0):

Another potential problem with not implementing the disposable pattern properly - it is very easy to *accidentally* call .Dispose() more than once. If your Dispose method does not check for successive calls to it, and  (eg.) attempts to free up an unmanaged resource more than once, you might end up with some unrecoverable error, or unexpected behaviour.